# My custom server control is generated as System.Web.UI.UserControl in the designer file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I created a server control which consist only of fews buttons.

**CWNavigation.vb**

```
<ToolboxData("<{0}:CWNavigation runat=""server""></{0}:CWNavigation>")> _
<DefaultProperty("Id")> _
Public Class CWNavigation
    Inherits WebControl
```

I then referenced it in my ASPX page. Take note that the control are in the same solution, same project located in Commun/Navigation/CWNavigation.vb.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="NAV" TagName="CWNavigation" Src="~/Commun/Navigation/CWNavigation.vb" %>
```

I added it to the page.

```
<NAV:CWNavigation ID="CWNavigationService" runat="server" />
```

But the designer file along with the code-behind generate it as.

```
    Protected WithEvents CWNavigationService As Global.System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

But this is wrong.. it must be CWNavigation. Is there anything ive done wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its a custom Server Control you should register it as an assembly.  Something like this...

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Control.Assembly.CWNavigation" TagPrefix="NAV" TagName="CWNavigation" Namespace="Namespace.Of.Control.Assembly" %>
```

Or add it to your ToolBox (Context Menu->Choose Items) and then drag and drop (which will have Visual Studio wire it up for you).